# How to prove that $f'(x) = e^{-x} g(x)$?

Tags: exponential-function

Hello guys can someone help me with that?

I tried all the ways but it always leads me far away from the wanted result.

> Given $g(x)= e^{x}-x-1$ and $f(x)=x-1+(x+2)e^{-x}$, 
>   prove that $f'(x) = e^{-x} g(x)$.

Comment: well after all I did, it ended up with f'(x) =e^(-x)+1- e^(-x) (x+2)

Comment: sorry but how to do this e^x?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is correct. We can factorise it as follows;
$$f'(x)=1+e^{-x}(-x-1)=e^{-x}(e^x-x-1)=e^{-x}g(x)$$

Comment: $e^{-x}\times e^x=e^{-x+x}=e^0=1$. So we can factorise $1$ as $1=e^{-x}\times e^x$.